# Adjust height of a row in Tkinter Treeview depending on wraped strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I was making a treeview for my tkinter program, and when I insert the data into it, there are some rows with too many characters and some of them are unseen.

Is there any way to set an auto line feed for the row height? I don't want to add a horizontal scrollbar to solve this. This means when the width of a strings is bigger then th columns with a newline should be iserted (automaticly). In that case the height of the row should be adjusted (automaicly) in that case to display more then one line.

[image: picture]

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, height=15,
                    columns=('c1', 'c2'),
                    show="headings")
tree.column('c1', width=100, anchor='center')
tree.column('c2', width=200, anchor='center')
tree.heading('c1', text='text1')
tree.heading('c2', text='text2')
tree.pack()

tree.insert('', 1, values=['edew', 'dewd'])
tree.insert('', 2, values=['abcd'*10, 'wxyz'*10])

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly would you want it to look like when there's a very long string inside? Could you provide an image for that as well?

Comment: Your examle is far away from being minimal.

Comment: I am interestd in an answer, too. That is why edit the question and the code.

Comment: I tried to use a `image` for each element with `heigth=50` but the row doesn't adjust to this.

Answer (score 1):

The height of alls row can be modified with this code.

```
root = Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=45)
```

It would be very nice to know if each row in a Treeview can have it's own style to defined individual rowheight (depending on newline characters).

Comment: I have a project with 3 different treeviews, and I have tried to use :
`style = ttk.Style(root)`
`style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=45)`

But then it changes the row height for all treeviews , not for the treeview that I wanted. I have tried to change the `root` but it didnt work, can you please help me with this? How can I change the row height just for specific treeview

Answer (score 1):

In response to Aleksandar Beat's question:

In order to change the style of a specific `Treeview`, you have to define a different identifier before the ttk widget name:

```
Style().configure('AnythingYouWantHere.Treeview', rowheight=45)
# The '.Treeview' can not be changed
```

However, if you do it this way, you have to specify the `style` option of the ttk widget.

Sample usage:

```
root = Tk()
Style().configure('MyStyle1.Treeview', rowheight=45) 
styledTreeView = Treeview(root, style='MyStyle1.Treeview')
normalTreeView = Treeview(root) # Style will not automatically apply
```

This also applies to any ttk widgets.